# while loop to the infinity when I try to retrieve checked Item from selectManyCheckbox

Tags: java, jsf

I want to recuperate from a checkbox a list  of item checked, the problem that when I iterate the list to retrieve the item checked the instruction while  loop to the infinite
this is my code:

**JSF:**

```
  <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{TestAjax.selectedItemscheckbox}">
<f:selectItem itemValue="priority.pname" itemLabel="By priority" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="project.pname" itemLabel="By project" />    
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

**The code:**

```
public Class TestAjax {

private ArrayList<String> selectedItemscheckbox;  //list of checkbox used for grouping


public ArrayList<String> getSelectedItemscheckbox() {
    return selectedItemscheckbox;
}

public void setSelectedItemscheckbox(ArrayList<String> selectedItemscheckbox) {
    this.selectedItemscheckbox = selectedItemscheckbox;
}


public void CreateQueryNumber()
{ 
 Iterator it= selectedItemscheckbox.iterator();
 System.out.println("checkeddddddddddd"+selectedItemscheckbox);

 while(it.hasNext())  ===>loop to the  infinity
 {
   System.out.println("one"+ it.toString());
 select ="select count(jiraissue.id) as nb";
 from ="jiraissue j ,priority pr ,project proj";
 where="j.project=proj.id";
 jointure="j.priority =pr.id";
 groupBy="group by "+it.toString();

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't making any call to it.next(). To fix this, you can either add an it.next() at the end of your loop:

```
  while(it.hasNext()){
       .... bla bla bla ....
       it.next();
  }
```

or use something like:

```
  Object obj;
  while((obj = it.next()) != null){
       .... bla bla bla ....
  }
```

Comment: ,thank you I have puted it.toString() instead of it.next() , this because I haven't drink my coffee yet :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `it.next()` to jump the iterator to the next value.

```
while(it.hasNext())
{
  String i_str = it.next().toString();
  System.out.println( "one"+ i_str );
  select ="select count(jiraissue.id) as nb";
  from ="jiraissue j ,priority pr ,project proj";
  where="j.project=proj.id";
  jointure="j.priority =pr.id";
  groupBy="group by "+i_str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you still on Java 1.4 or older? You're already on 1.5 or newer, right? Use the [enhanced for loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

```
for (String selectedItem : selectedItemscheckbox) {
    System.out.println(selectedItem);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you and I want to ask you ,by using this loop what are the advantages ?